# How to retrieve submit button with getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to get the a submit button using `getElementsByTagName` but I must be doing something wrong.

```
 <p id="ptag">Want to find out if this works</p>     

 <button>The Button</button>

 <form>
 First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
 Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="yes" value="yes">A checkbox<br> 
 <input type="submit" value="Login">
 </form>
```

in the above HTML snippet, If I use the below function, getting the button works yet getting the submit button does not.

```
 window.onload = theFunction;

 function theFunction(){

 document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")[0].setAttribute("onclick", "theOtherFunction()");

 document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[3];.setAttribute("onclick", "theOtherFunction()");

 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
 function theOtherFunction(){

   document.getElementById("ptag").style.color = "blue";

 }
```

I added `theOtherFunction()` to my question because all my little experiment is doing is changing that `<p>` color to blue.  With the button, it stays blue.  With the submit button, it quickly turns blue and then goes back to black.  What is the difference and how can I use the submit button to retain changes?

Comment: There's a stray semicolon in the statement. **Always** have the developer console open to see errors reported by the browser!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at your last line of code `document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[3];.setAttribute("onclick", "theOtherFunction()");`

There is a ; you don't want there right after the [3].
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery becomes very useful here

```
$('input[type="submit"]')
```

This will allow you to make html changes with immunity and support older browsers that still have 1% usage.

Your 2nd example should work without the ; in the middle of the line. However not all browsers support getElementsByTagName.

**Update using no ready made libs.**

If you are a build it yourself person, who wants to make his own lib.

```
function getElementsByAttrib(attrib) {
    return document.querySelectorAll('[' + attrib + ']');
}
var elements = getElementsByAttrib('type="submit"');
MySubmit = elements[0]';
```

Comment: Loading a huge and needless library for this is counter productive

Comment: @PeeHaa point taken but often jQuery can come in handy to accomplish more than its signature feature of dom traversal.

Comment: I really like this and for what I am doing, JQuery isn't really ideal.

Answer (score 3):

It's not practical to target/retrieve specific input elements with getElementsByTagName.

We gotta use the right tool for the right job and in this case it's the query selector like this...

```
var S=document.querySelectorAll('input[type=submit]');

S[0].style.background='red'; // do something to the first button
```

NB: Code above assumes you only have one submit button or you'll have to loop through the array "S" to target all submit buttons.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do that if the element in question is in another namespace? Currently I use `document.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'button')` to retrieve it, but I cannot seem to be able to set the content (innerHTML).